# Windows phone 8 - Pivot Active, Inactive Header template

Tags: xaml, mobile, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I'd like to use different templates for the header of my pivot, if it's selected/active id like to use template A, if it's inactive/not selected, I'd like to use template B.

What I would like to do is pretty much the same as the facebook app for windows phone, where a small triangle/arrow is displayed on the active pivot. I'm not 100% sure how this is designed, if the icon and arrow is the header template, or if it's just the arrow, or if it's pivot at all...

I would appreciate if someone would shed some light on how this kind of UI can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with a work-around for this

I removed the pivot header entirely and created a stand alone control to navigate the pivot

The nav-viewmodel, shared between the pivot and the Nav control, have a SelectedPage property, which changes when you navigate in the Nav control:

```
<AppControls:Nav Grid.Row="0"/>
```

That gives me full control of the layout of the selected menu item.
The SelectedPage property is bound to the pivots selectedindex:

full markup:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Nav, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Background="#E8E8E8">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <AppControls:Nav Grid.Row="0"/>
        <phone:Pivot SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainGui">
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="FrontPage">

                <AppControls:Topnav Grid.Row="1" />

            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="PlacesPage">
                <AppControls:PlacesControl Grid.Row="1"/>
            </phone:PivotItem>            
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="MapPage">
                <AppControls:MapControl Grid.Row="1"/>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="SettingsPage">
                <AppControls:Settings Grid.Row="1" />
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>



    </Grid>
```